# Bat как удалить не числовой символ в строке

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, powershell

После работы предыдущего bat скрипта получил txt файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это значения в КБ сколько занимают оперативной памяти процессы одной программы "Допустим Chrome". Визуально в консоли это выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разделитель между цифрами это не пробел. Кодировка консоли 866. Подскажите как убрать разделитель между цифрами. И сохранить значения в том же порядке в файл (столбик). Цельное значение без разделителя мне нужно для получения суммы всех этих значений.

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж указан тэг `powershell`, держите однострочник:

`(Get-Content '.\file.txt') -replace '[^\d]'`

Если нужно вывести в файл:

`(Get-Content '.\file.txt') -replace '[^\d]' | Out-File .\newFile.txt`

А вот, чтобы сразу суммировать:

`(Get-Content '.\file.txt') -replace '[^\d]' | Measure-Object -Sum`

Ну и напоследок, чтобы получить память по процессам firefox (в байтах):

`Get-Process -ProcessName firefox | Measure-Object -Property WorkingSet -Sum`

Answer (score -1):

Если разделитель - это постоянный символ - **я** , то проще обработать текстовый файл **list.txt** обычным парсингом bat-файлов, выводя данные в другой файл **listout.txt**.
При указании разделителя строки (в параметре **delims**) следует следить за кодировкой, чтобы он совпал с требуемым.

```
@for /f "delims=я tokens=1,2" %%a in (list.txt) do @echo.%%a %%b>>listout.txt
```

Если же символ разделителем становится любой отличный от цифры знак, то можно вынести обработку строк в отдельную процедуру обработки строки.

```
@for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (list.txt) do @call:Num %%a>>listout.txt

@goto end


:Num
@echo off
@Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 @Set _str=%1
 @Set _str=%_str:"=%
 @set str=
 @For /l %%g in (0,1,8191) do (
  @Set "_char=!_str:~%%g,1!"
  @if not defined _char ((@echo.!str!)&@ENDLOCAL& @goto end)
  @set p=!_char!
  @if 0 gtr !_char! @set "p= "
  @if 9 lss !_char! @set "p= "

  @set str=!str!!p!
  @set str=!str:  = !
 )
@ENDLOCAL 
@goto end

:end
```

Comment: Это не сработает так как символ "я" на самом деле это пробел. Только, что попробовал ваш вариант не работает.

Comment: Ну тогда, надо уточнить формат входного файла для обработки: какая у него кодовая страница, каково значение разделителя в определенной кодировке (unicode,win1251,866) ?

Comment: Кодировка консоли 866. Кодировка выходных текстовых файлов ANSI. Кодировка bat-файла utf-8.

Comment: Если в самом bat файле установить кодировку chcp 65001 т.е utf-8 то на выходе получу текстовые файлы utf-8. В самом текстовом файле визуально разделителем будет выступать пробел а не "я" как в случае с ANSI. В for delims по умолчанию это пробел но такой for ничего не даст @for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (list.txt) do @echo.%%a %%b>>listout.txt

Comment: Если точное значение символа разделителя не известно - проблемы из-за кодировки. Тогда воспользуйтесь вторым вариантом в ответе.